# Multiple addresses using XCode Mapkit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, mapkit

I am very new to XCode and objective-c. This question may have been answered previously but I am somehow not able to make it work. My objective is to show multiple annotations on Google map. I have a bunch of Lats and Longs, however so far I have been able to show only one annotation. How can I show All the annotations at once. I have the code below for the `MKMapView`-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    // Set some coordinates for our position
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;

    location.latitude = (double) 44.271745;
    location.longitude = (double) -88.453265;   
    // Add the annotation to our map view
    MapViewAnnotation *newAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:@"Appleton" andCoordinate:location];
    [self.mapview addAnnotation:newAnnotation];

    [newAnnotation release];

    self.mapview.region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location,100000,100000);
}
```

I understand that I can loop through and instantiate `newAnnotation` and then use `addAnnotation` to add the annotation. But I am somehow not getting how to do it. This may be very basic, but I am very new to this. Any help will be appreciated.

```
//
//  MapViewAnnotation.h
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MapViewAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {

    NSString *title;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)ttl andCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c2d;

@end
```

And

```
//
//  MapViewAnnotation.m
//

#import "MapViewAnnotation.h"


@implementation MapViewAnnotation
@synthesize title, coordinate;

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)ttl andCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c2d {
    [super init];
    title = ttl;
    coordinate = c2d;
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [title release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you only have one location. You should have list of latitude and longitude, then loop through that list and instantiate the MapViewAnnotation.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSArray *arrayOfLatLong = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"10.22", @"20.212", nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Lat",@"Long",nil]], 
                               [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"10.22", @"24.5", nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Lat",@"Long",nil]], nil];


    for(NSDictionary *location in arrayOfLatLong) {
        CGFloat latitude = [[location valueForKey:@"Lat"] floatValue];
        CGFloat longitude = [[location valueForKey:@"Long"] floatValue];

        CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
        location.latitude = latitude;
        location.longitude = latitude;   
        MapViewAnnotation *newAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:@"Appleton" andCoordinate:location];
        [self.mapview addAnnotation:newAnnotation];

        [newAnnotation release];
        self.mapview.region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location,100000,100000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I did change the code as per your answer (replaced the Lat-10.22 and long-24.5 with my Lat and long), but it gives me an error `location undefined` at the `self.mapview.region =...` line.

Comment: see the updated code. The last location is being used as the region of the mapview

Comment: Ok I changed it again and included the `self.mapview.region=...` inside the `for` loop and it works now. One more question- How di I add more values (of lat and longs) to the array.

Comment: Depends if you have a more lat longs. Where you should get the lat long location?

Comment: I do have it, pretty much static list (not from a database or anything for now). Like (43.426121,-88.200216) , (46.2880535,-96.1095356) and so on..

Comment: See this link http://maybelost.com/2011/01/a-basic-mapview-and-annotation-tutorial/ but on viewDidLoad make like the code above

Comment: Thanks, yes I did use that link as a reference for the code. The multiple annotations works great now. However, I now have a bigger issue of showing all the annotations on the same view and not have to drag on to different directions

Comment: You can post another question so that others can also cooperate